# Understanding new Meteor.Collection

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to follow along in a book to learn Meteor. The problem that I ran into is in the book he used the console to insert data into the collection. Because I am using Windows I need to run mine on a VPS.

So when I put this .js file together;

```
PlayersList = new Meteor.Collection('players');

PlayersList.insert ({
name: 'David',
score: 0,
name: 'Bob',
score: 0,
name: 'Mary',
score: 0,
name: 'Bill',
score: 0,
name: 'Warren',
score: 0,
name: 'Tim',
score: 0
});
```

now every time I change something I get more and more players. So it appears that it doesn't really create a new Collection but keeps adding to an existing one. How would I set this up so that I can remain on the same page as the book?

Comment: That's either a typo or equivalent to `{name: 'Tim', score:0}`. I think you are missing an opening `[` some `},{` and a closing `]`

Comment: So they should all be on their own line like    PlayersList.insert({name:'Tim', score:0})?

Comment: I think, to do more than one, the outer structure needs to look like an array, e.g. `PlayersList.insert([{name:'David', score:0},{name:'Bob',score:0}]);`  been a few months since I did any Meteor though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your insertion code gets reexecuted everytime your application is restarted.

You need to insert your test data on the server only once, like this :

`server/startup.js`

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  // always start from scratch with clean test data, remove this line when
  // debugging is done to stop clearing collection data after every server restart
  PlayersList.remove({});
  if(PlayersList.find().count()===0){
    // insertion code goes here
    var playersNames=["David","Bob",...];
    _.each(playersNames,function(playerName){
      PlayersList.insert({
        name:playerName,
        score:0
      });
    });
  }
});
```